# Problems compiling x86 assembly on x64 linux

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86

I tried compiling assembly code written in X86 on a x64 ubuntu, and got the following errors:

```
gcc -m32 -o T Tirgul3b_Hello.s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the code I tried to compile:

```
    #This is a simple "Hello World!" program
    .section    .rodata #read only data section
str:    .string "Hello World!\n"
    ########
    .text   #the beginnig of the code
.globl  main    #the label "main" is used to state the initial point of this program
    .type   main, @function # the label "main" representing the beginning of a function
main:   # the main function:
    pushl   %ebp        #save the old frame pointer
    movl    %esp,   %ebp    #create the new frame pointer

    pushl   $str        #the string is the only paramter passed to the printf function.
    call    printf      #calling to printf AFTER we put its parameters in the stack.

    #return from printf:
    movl    $0, %eax    #return value is zero (just like in c - we tell the OS that this program finished seccessfully)
    movl    %ebp,   %esp    #restore the old stack pointer - release all used memory.
    popl    %ebp        #restore old frame pointer (the caller function frame)
    ret         #return to caller function (OS)
```

What am I missing here and how do I fix it?

If there is any extra information you need, ask in comments.

Comment: Try installing multilib versions of gcc and g++. `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib`

Comment: That did the trick. Had a hunch it was missing libraries, but didn't know any way to find out which. Wanna write the answer so I can accept it, or should I do it?

Comment: You can answer, but it is similar to some other questions on SO I've seen on the subject in the past. Your question isn't a duplicate but it isn't new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Petch said, installing the `gcc` and `g++` `multilib` libraries did the trick. I installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```